# EC2 Windows Instances Initializing Twice

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, launch, reboot

I am using AWS to run micro instances of Windows 2008 R2 SP1 Datacenter edition, using a custom AMI derived from `ami-cbc87da2`.

I am experiencing a strange behavior that appears to be a reboot of these instances immediately after launch. Specifically, what I am seeing is that the status of the instance (as displayed in AWS Management Console) starts as `... initializing` and then changes to `2/2 checks passed` before returning to `... initializing` and finally changes to a stable status of `2/2 checks passed`.

I am able to establish an RDP connection to the instance when it first reaches `2/2 checks passed` status, but this connection is lost once the instance returns to `... initializing`. A permanent connection is only possible during the second `2/2 checks passed` phase.

Initially I suspected that this problem was caused by my custom AMI, so I repeated the experiment using the original Windows 2008 AMI. It was still present.

I also suspected that the problem was caused by my C# code that launches instances via the AWS API, so I tried launching instances manually from AWS Management Console. Again, the symptom is still present.

It seems implausible that an instance of an original Windows AMI launched purely using AWS tooling should fail like this, so I assume I am doing something stupid, but I can't imagine what it is.

Thanks, in advance for your suggestions.

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else runs across this issue, here is what I have discovered:

As explained to me by the AWS support team, this is intended behavior for Windows instances, which execute Sysprep immediately after launch and must therefore reboot for the Sysprep settings to take effect.

I was concerned that my custom launch script (which is passed into the instance as user data) was being executed during the initial boot and ignored during the reboot. In fact, AWS support team confirmed that user data is ignored during the initial boot and processed only during the reboot. More details [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=380785&#380785).

BTW, kudos to the AWS support team. Even their free public forum support service is helpful, responsive and well-informed. Why would anyone pay for support when you can get such great support for free? :)